# Can I sort an iterator without converting it to an array?

Tags: php, iterator

I have an object `$iterator` that implements the `Iterator` interface and I want to sort all items inside.

```
class MyIterator implements Iterator
{
    public function current() {
        return rand(0,10);
    }
}
$iterator = new MyIterator();
uasort($iterator, function($a, $b) {

});
```

Unfortunately: `uasort()` and `ArrayIterator::uasort()` only works for arrays and I may have to convert the array to an iterator by using `iterator_to_array()`

Edit: Don't use Doctrine query builder iteration anymore as example.

Comment: How should the iterator get sorted otherwise, if it should not load all rows? If the data comes from the database, why not sort it there?

Comment: Agreed. The whole point of the Iterator interface is to allow processing a collection of objects without loading them all into memory at the same time - you won't be able to sort them without doing that. Modifying the order of an iterator should be done by modifying the underlying data.

Comment: I agree that the database is a bad example. I change it.

Comment: What is the problem in the first place (what you iterate over, where is data coming from)? Sorry, but it is hard to advise something based on the provided example.

Comment: Well. I want to sort view model data in the view (``{$users|sort:"name:asc"}``). But the view doesn't know if the data comes from an ``Iterator`` only or is an native array. I only sees an ``iterable`` object. The sorting mechanics should be able to sort both, and all I want is to optimize that a bit, without iterating over all items first.

Comment: @MikeReiche, as array sorting functions are already available (and "native"), I guess, it is better to unify every traversable to arrays. The good approach to optimization is to do it only when you actually face performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

I cant. I had to convert it to an array first.

```
public function sort(iterable $iterator, $expression) {
    if (is_array($iterator)===false) {
        $iterator = iterator_to_array($iterator);
    }
}
```